# Does recvfrom() get the return value from the length field of UDP header

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I am working with Ethernet card API to emulate the BSD `recvfrom`. Currently, I return the length of message as `(length field in UDP header - 8 )` bytes. 8 is the size of UDP header.

Is this the correct way? Does the BSD `recvfrom()` gets the length of payload message in this way?

How to get the BSD UDP source code, such as `<sys/socket.h>`?

Comment: Here are the source code of `recvfrom()` in freebsd. [recvfrom()](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/uipc_syscalls.c?im=excerpts#L1291).

Comment: @SSC Thank you. But I don't understand code you pointed. why the parameters of recvfrom() be commented out. I don't have experience of reading those kernel code.

Comment: The commented out part you mentioned are the comments, the parameters are stored in the `struct recvfrom_args`.  I think it is there to save time, so others won't have to look the `struct recvfrom_args` up.